# Git - How to Stop This Type of Merge Conflict

Tags: git

```html
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======
>>>>>>> master
COPY image/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod o+x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

<<<<<<< HEAD


=======
>>>>>>> master
```

As you can see, there is no real merge conflict here.
I know that both branches have the same exact code there, but the placement is a few lines off.

I've already tried `git merge -Xignore-all-space` but this is actually the result of it.

Any ideas on how to avoid these weird merge conflicts?

Comment: I don't think you can (at least not that I have ever seen). you touched the same lines of code in two different branches. Git is going to default to needing human intervention.

Comment: "As you can see, there is no real merge conflict here." That's not what I see. You'd have a clearer mental picture of what has happened here if you did a 3-way diff, but it is evident that the two contributors have edited some blank lines in two different ways, and that is indeed a merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Given the little information available, my best bet is that there's a conflict on whitespace.

Check commits on both branches with `git show -R` which should highlight trailing whitespaces that can be missed with a regular "forward" `git diff`/`git show`.

If it helps, my git version is `2.31.0`.